# ListBoxArray .GetIndex method not working properly.

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, c#-4.0

When I try to get Index of selected item of listbox from ListBoxArray using 
ListBoxArray.GetIndex method it is returning me wrong index number.

This listbox item has selectionmode multisimple.I need the index of last selected item.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
Dim item = ListBox1.SelectedItems(ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count - 1)
```

It will return the last item of the items you selected in the list.

Once you hace the last item, you can get it's index using FindIndex on the whole list.

Here an example if the list contains strings:

```
 Dim ind As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String). _
        ToList().FindIndex(Function(x) x = item.ToString())
```

If you list objets are of another type just change the Cast(of) type.